# Issue with expandable listview android

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

Please help me. am struck with this issue. I have an expandable listview which display item title from db. On the group item click I want get that id(id from database). any hope. am getting group id but it's not fullfill my requirement. please help me.

```
@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(JobDetails.this, "Group Expanded" + groupPosition,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    plusView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
    plusView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.minus));
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(JobDetails.this, "Group Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    plusView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
    plusView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.plus));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey solve this by adding id in arraylist and call it on "public View getGroupView"..simple